# Cannot Launch CloudFormation Stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot open this file because of an error: must
> reference a valid S3 object to which you have access

Let me lay out some context that will prevent incorrect responses.

- I am using an account I have had for several years.
- I have tried using both the root and AdministratorAccess enabled IAM role.
- I have created an account managed by this account as a parent and tried there.
- I am using a [CloudFormation template from AWS Well Architected Labs](https://www.wellarchitectedlabs.com/operational-excellence/100_labs/100_inventory_patch_management/3_deploy_env_iaac/).

I log in to console, go to CloudFormation, select create stack and that is when I hit the blocker. Despite the error, CloudFormation CREATES the bucket and object.

Here is the really strange parts:

- My colleague tried to recreate. He did not encounter same issue.
- I set up a brand new account, completely separate from this one (i.e. not managed in the organization) and I could not recreate.

That is correct, when I set up a new account, completely separate, the stack would create just fine.

I thought maybe over the years, I had accumulated some bad policies or roles that were causing me issues - so I cleaned up shop right down to bare essentials. STILL getting the error.

Right now, I can just use my brand spanking new account and I don't need to worry about this. However, I am completely stumped by what is causing this issue. I cannot see any reason why this error is appearing. And I would really like to continue to use my main account which I have held for several years and has all my domains registered.

I am using Admin IAM roles and even Root accounts. I am experiencing same issue in child accounts to my parent accounts but NOT in completely separate accounts. I see no policy, role or any other restriction listed anywhere on AWS that restricts CloudFormation in any way. It is even creating buckets and objects when I click "Create Stack".

I am completely stumped and I guess I would like to be ale to understand what has corrupted my account and its ability to use this feature?

Comment: Your setup is not clear. So your bucket with a template are in one account, and you want to create a stack in a second account?

Comment: Look carefully at the events from the deployment that failed. It will tell you what resource failed, and you can compare that to the template.

Comment: Without information about the template, or the event log for the stack creation, it is difficult to make any assumption about what is causing the issue, but it sure sounds iam policy or resource policy related.